# How to make a full-page screenshot with Sikuli?

Tags: sikuli

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make a full-page screenshot with Sikuli?
It seems that this tool is capable of screenshots of the current window.
reference: https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screen.html

Comment: Are you using Jython? Java?

Comment: Selenium in Java, so both Java and Javascript are available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SikuliX features you can only capture, what is currently visible on the screen.

If you want to capture the whole page, you have to use other tools available (e.g. browser features) and trigger the action appropriately from within your SikuliX workflow.